# What Bible Verses are Considered Contrary to Eternal Security?

Tags: biblical-basis, soteriology, perseverance-of-saints, eternal-security

Upon questioning, eternal security advocates (those who say a Christian cannot lose their salvation), will point to a variety of Bible verses to support their position. So, this begs the question of what Bible verses support ones ability to lose their salvation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been a hotly debated topic in Christianity.  Both sides cite biblical passages to support their views and each side attacks the other's interpretation of the other’s proof texts. For example, one of the important texts for eternal security, or "once saved always saved", is from John  10.

> 27“My sheep hear My voice, and I know them, and they follow Me; 28and
> I give eternal life to them, and they will never perish; and no one
> will snatch them out of My hand.

There is, however, an assumption in this verse which is that the sheep are listening to Jesus’ voice and following him. If they stop doing that, they are no longer his sheep. No one can take them out of his hand, true, but they can take themselves out of his hand.

The Bible as a whole shows this to be true. I will provide a few of the many passages which support this view, while highlighting key words from the NASB. Salvation is contingent upon continued obedience and perseverance in the faith.

> Luke 9 62 But Jesus said to him, “No one, after putting his hand to
> the plow and looking back, is fit for the kingdom of God.”
>
> John 8 31  So Jesus was saying to those Jews who had **believed Him**, “If
> **you continue in My word**, then you are truly disciples of Mine;
>
> Mt 7 22-23 “Many will say to Me on that day, ‘Lord, Lord, did we not
> prophesy in Your name, and in Your name cast out demons, and in Your
> name perform many miracles?’ “And then I will declare to them, ‘I
> never knew you; DEPART FROM ME, YOU WHO **PRACTICE LAWLESSNESS**.
>
> Mark 13:13 And you will be hated by everyone because of My name, but
> it is the one who has **endured to the end who will be saved.**
>
> Ro 11 20-21  Quite right, they were broken off for their unbelief, but
> you **stand by your fait**h. Do not be conceited, but fear; for if God did
> not spare the natural branches, **He will not spare you, either**.
>
> 1 Cor 9 27  but I discipline my body and make it my slave, so that,
> after I have preached to others, I myself will not be
> **disqualified**.
>
> Gal 5 19-21 Now the deeds of the flesh are evident, which are:
> immorality, impurity, sensuality, 20idolatry, sorcery, enmities,
> strife, jealousy, outbursts of anger, disputes, dissensions,
> factions, 21envying, drunkenness, carousing, and things like these, of
> which I forewarn you, just as I have forewarned you, that those who
> **practice such things will not inherit the kingdom of God.**
>
> Hebrews 10:26-29 For if we go on sinning willfully after receiving the
> knowledge of the truth, there no longer remains a sacrifice for sins,
>
> 2 PETER 2:20-21 For if, after they have escaped the defilements of the
> world by the knowledge of the Lord and Savior Jesus Christ, they are
> again entangled in them and are overcome, the last state has become
> worse for them than the first. For it would be better for them not to
> have known the way of righteousness, than having known it, to turn
> away from the holy commandment handed on to them.
>
> Rev 3 5 ‘He who **overcomes** will thus be clothed in white garments;
> and I will not erase his name from the book of life, and I will
> confess his name before My Father and before His angels.

The Bible does not promise anyone eternal security. It promises eternal life to those who maintain their faith in Jesus Christ and follow him in obedience until the end. "Once saved always saved" is one of the most pernicious heresies that exists because it lulls people into a false sense of security, and helps them justify continuing to engage in willful sinful behavior, which the Bible strongly admonishes against.